# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I read the FAQ, and question seems to fix.
Why was it closed?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838651/what-html-video-players-that-work-in-the-android-browser-are-there-for-android-4

Comment: It is not a suitable question. It isn't about a specific programming issue. It is a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and as such not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is it suitable for? superuser?

Comment: In this form I would not know of any site within the network that would be appropriate.

Comment: It is not suitable for anywhere here. Q&A sites need questions with Answers. There is no correct Answer to your question. You want a Question and Discussion site, or Question and Polling site instead (Whatever they are).

Comment: Why do you mean there is no correct answer? The answer X.Y embeeded player which is open source or not....

Comment: There is possibly no single correct answer. That is, you would end up with a list of answers, one not more correct than the other. That's simply not what we do.

Comment: Also, even if there *was* a correct answer, who is to say it will still be the correct answer in 6 months time? A newer, better HTML video player may well come out, making the question and answer even less useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the reason for your question got closed

[image]

The question is not constructive.

As Oded said, the question isn't about a specific programming issue. It is a shopping question and as such not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can see their answer but it is pretty obscure. Not constructive. SHould I accept that judgment by face value?

Comment: Yes. It's the current policy.